# Allocating payments to invoices in two different databases with duplicate values

Tags: sql, ms-access

Bit of a long shot as I'm not sure how this would be possible.  But here goes:

R is located in Table 1 T1 which is in Database 1 D1.  R is located in Table 2 T2 which is in Database 2 D2.  Each R in T1 has only one corresponding R in T2.  Each corresponding R in both T1 and T2 have their own unique identifiers, but they do not match.

There are a number of columns in T1 and T2 that match ("invoice date", "invoice number", "net amount", "tax amount" and "supplier").

T1 and T2 also have a number of columns that don't match and it is these columns I am interested in ("job" in T1 and "outstanding invoice balance" in T2).

I began by creating a join in a query between the columns (fields) that match in T1 and T2 ("invoice date" etc) thinking that this would link the corresponding R in T1 to their one corresponding R in T2.  And for the most part this worked.

However, I noticed that some of the Rs had duplicate values for ALL the join fields and therefore were not linking to their correct R in the corresponding table.

Assuming I can't change the dynamics of either database and their respective tables, how can I link the corresponding Rs if they have duplicate values in the join fields?

Other info that may prove useful is that each R has a "date time" stamp in both tables reflecting when the record was created.  The corresponding Rs in T1 and T2 annoyingly don't have the same "date time" stamp, but invariably they will be pretty close ( a few miliseconds apart).  This also means that the Rs in T1 that are producing duplicate values will have slightly different time stamps.  In fact what this means is if there are duplicate records, the first record in T1 (ie the one with the earliest date time stamp in T1) will have been allocated to the correct corresponding R in T2 (again, with the earliest date time stamp).

The only way that  I could think of making this work was to create multiple queries and slowly eliminating the records that have correctly been matched.  So the first query would show all records, many with the correct corresponding matched record, but others that are duplicate.  The second query would remove the unique ids of the records in T1 and the respective unique IDs for the Rs in T2 that matched correctly (ie no duplicates), as well as the first record of every duplicate (as these have seemingly been allocated correctly).  The remaining records in T1 and T2 have now had their duplicate removed or may still have a few duplicates.  We now rerun the first query with these remaining records, which should mean that more Rs in T1 correctly match to their corresponding Rs in T2, with potentially some duplicates still remaining.  The whole thing is then repeated until there are no duplicates and each R in T1 is allocated to its corresponding R in T2.

This is what I have to work with and I've tried to logically set out what I wish to accomplish.  If you have any further questions please let me know, but If you can tell me whether this is possible and how to get it done, or whether it's not possible at all, I would be really grateful.

Comment: A few questions: With your duplicates, does the single row in T1 match multiple rows in T2, or do multiple rows in T1 match to multiple rows in T2? Are you attempting to write a SELECT query to match the records, or clean up the data? When you say "changing the dynamics", do you mean you can't change table structures by adding a new column?

Comment: Sample data and desired results do wonders to explain what needs to be done.